# error TS2339: Property 'addHours' does not exist on type 'Date'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, spfx

Line 729 of lib.es5.d.ts file has :

```
interface Date {
 addHours: (h: any) => any;
    /** Returns a string representation of a date. The format of the string depends on the locale. */
```

So why a line like:

```
const newdatetime =   myDateValue.addHours( -1 );
```

errors with error TS2339: Property 'addHours' does not exist on type 'Date' ?
Is there another way to add hours in typescript?
Now I did :

```
 debugger;
  const myDateValue = new Date();
  const newdatetime =   myDateValue.addHours( -1 );
  console.log(newdatetime);
```

and the gulp serve had the error:
Error - [tsc] src/webparts/ecgTsxDpcKendo/components/EcgTsxDpcRequestForm.tsx(44,37): error TS2339: Property 'addHours' does not exist on type 'Date'.
I should say this is in an SPFx workbench

Comment: Show some more codes, it seems some typo in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I've never hear of the `addHours()` method. You should use [`setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours).

It's very simple:

```js
const myDateValue = new Date();
myDateValue.setHours(myDateValue.getHours() - 1);
console.log(myDateValue);
```

This also works when it's midnight for example. If the current hour is 0 and you subtract 1 the hour for `Date` object will become 23 (or 11PM) on the previous day.

> please note that `setHours()` doesn't return a new date object, but modifies itself.